# Grader Valgrind returning "Use of uninitialised value of size 8"

Tags: c, algorithm, initialization

I'm writing some functions for a poker game, running it with my input and debugging with Valgrind returns no errors, but when I run it through the course grader with their input using Valgrind, it returns this error message:

```
Grading at Wed 02 Mar 2022 10:45:38 PM UTC
Compiling your code
rm -f test poker cards.o my-test-main.o *~
cc -ggdb3 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=gnu99   -c -o deck.o deck.c
cc -ggdb3 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=gnu99   -c -o eval.o eval.c
cc -ggdb3 -Wall -Werror -pedantic -std=gnu99   -c -o cards.o cards.c
gcc -o test-eval -ggdb3 deck.o deck-c4.o eval-c4.o eval.o test-eval.o cards.o input.o future.o
Testcase 1: Trying hands with nothing  //<----- Poker hand with nothing special
Valgrind returned an error status
==220== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==220== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==220== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==220== Command: ./test-eval inp.1.txt
==220== Parent PID: 219
==220== 
==220== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==220==    at 0x109419: print_hand (deck.c:12)
==220==    by 0x10B9C6: describe_hand (in /graderhome/work/c3prj2_eval/test-eval)
==220==    by 0x10BBBE: main (in /graderhome/work/c3prj2_eval/test-eval)
==220== 
==220== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==220==    at 0x109419: print_hand (deck.c:12)
==220==    by 0x10B9C6: describe_hand (in /graderhome/work/c3prj2_eval/test-eval)
==220==    by 0x10BBE2: main (in /graderhome/work/c3prj2_eval/test-eval)
==220== 
==220== 
==220== HEAP SUMMARY:
==220==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==220==   total heap usage: 278 allocs, 278 frees, 14,160 bytes allocated
==220== 
==220== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==220== 
==220== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==220== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==220== ERROR SUMMARY: 10 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

`print_hand()` is some code that I've written in past assignments ( within `deck.c` ) that complements the one I'm struggling with ( `eval.c` ), it just calls `print_card()` for each card in the `hand`:

```
void print_hand(deck_t * hand){
  for(int i = 0; i < hand->n_cards; i++) {
    print_card(*hand->cards[i]);//Prints a card.  //<----Line 12 here!
    printf(" ");//Then a space.
  }
}
```

`print_card()` just receives a type `card_t` and prints it's `card_t.value` and `card_t.suit` as type `char`, for example: "As", "Qc", "6d". (A hand could be "Kd Kh Ks 9h 7c 7h 2h")

But I really don't think the error is coming from these codes I've written before, everything had to pass the grader for that assignment.
Even so I went back and initialized every variable as well as in the code of `eval.c` (where I presume the error is), even though they were not being dereferenced before being initialized with a value.
Everything still works as expected for me, but the grader system still returns the same error message using Valgrind.

I really don't understand why the error still persists.
*Could you please give me some help with this?

Thank you very much in advance.*

I'll post the code that I wrote for this assignment bellow ( `eval.c` ), is not that big of a code, but it's bigger than what I've seen here, **so please let me know if I shouldn't post this here**.

I should mention that all the structs, for example: `card_t` and `deck_t`, all function names, types and parameters were given to me, and **their** `main` calls these functions and the ones I've written in past assignments.

```
#include "eval.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

/*Return negative if card1 has higher value than card2
  and vice-versa for decreasing order.*/
int card_ptr_comp(const void * vp1, const void * vp2) {
  const card_t *const *cp1 = vp1;
  const card_t *const *cp2 = vp2;
  if((*cp1)->value == (*cp2)->value) {
    //Lower ranking == better.
    if((*cp1)->suit < (*cp2)->suit) return -1;
    if((*cp1)->suit > (*cp2)->suit) return 1;
    if((*cp1)->suit == (*cp2)->suit) return 0;
  }
  if((*cp1)->value != (*cp2)->value)return (*cp2)->value - (*cp1)->value;
  printf("\n card_ptr_comp: This shouldn't have happened. ");
  return 0;
}

//Checks if there is a flush in hand.
suit_t flush_suit(deck_t * hand) {
  assert(hand->n_cards > 0);
  int sp = 0, he = 0, di = 0, cl = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < hand->n_cards; i++) {
    switch((*hand->cards[i]).suit) {
    case SPADES:
      sp++;
      break;
    case HEARTS:
      he++;
      break;
    case DIAMONDS:
      di++;
      break;
    case CLUBS:
      cl++;
      break;
    default:
      printf("Card doesn't have a correct suit");
      break;
    }
  }
  /*Counts how many times each suit has appeared in the hand.
    If any is equal to 5, returns it, else, returns NUM_SUITS.*/
  if(sp >= 5) return SPADES;
  if(he >= 5) return HEARTS;
  if(di >= 5) return DIAMONDS;
  if(cl >= 5) return CLUBS;
  else return NUM_SUITS;
}

//Get the largest element in passed in array.
unsigned get_largest_element(unsigned * arr, size_t n) {
  int temp = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(arr[i] > temp) temp = arr[i];
  }
  return temp;
}

//Returns the lowest index of a pair or a 3 of a kind.
size_t get_match_index(unsigned * match_counts, size_t n,unsigned n_of_akind) {
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(n_of_akind == match_counts[i]) return i;
  }
  return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

//Finds secondary pair of cards in hand.
ssize_t  find_secondary_pair(deck_t * hand,
                 unsigned * match_counts,
                 size_t match_idx) {
  for(int i = 0; i < hand->n_cards; i++) {
    if(match_counts[i] > 1 && (*hand->cards[i]).value != (*hand->cards[match_idx]).value) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1; //Return -1 if nothing is found.
}

//Helper function to find index of 5 if the hand starts with an Ace
int where_5_at(deck_t * hand) {
  for(int i = 0; i < hand->n_cards; i++) {
    if((*hand->cards[i]).value == 5) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

//Helper function that looks for Straights.
int straight_helper(deck_t *hand, size_t index, suit_t fs) {
  int check = 1, dif = 0;
  card_t temp = *hand->cards[0];
  for(int i = index; i < hand->n_cards; i++) {
    if(i == index) { //If first iteration, set temp to card at index.
      temp = *hand->cards[i];
      continue;
    }
    dif = temp.value - (*hand->cards[i]).value;
    if(dif == 0) continue; //If the value of both cards are the same, continue.
    if(dif == 1) { //If dif is 1, hand->cards[i] is adding to the Straight.
      check++;
      if(check == 5) return 1; //If check is equal to 5, there is a Straight in hand.
      temp = *hand->cards[i];
      continue;
    }
    if(dif > 1) return 0; //If dif > 1, there is no Straight in the hand.
  }
  return 0;
}

//Helper function that looks for Straight Flushes.
int straightFlush_helper(deck_t *hand, size_t index, suit_t fs) {
  if((*hand->cards[index]).suit != fs) return 0;
  int check = 1, strike = 0, dif = 0;
  card_t temp = *hand->cards[0];
  for(int i = index; i < hand->n_cards; i++) {
    if(i == index) { //If first iteration, set temp to card at index.
      temp = *hand->cards[i];
      continue;
    }
    dif = temp.value - (*hand->cards[i]).value;
    //If strike = 1.
    if(strike == 1) {
      if(dif == 1 && (*hand->cards[i]).suit == fs) { //If [i] suit is fs it adds to the Straight Flush.
    strike = 0;
    check++;
    if(check == 5) return 1; //If check is equal to 5, there is a Straight in hand.
    temp = *hand->cards[i];
    continue;
      }
      if(dif == 1 && (*hand->cards[i]).suit != fs) {
    strike = 2;
    continue;
      }
      return 0;
    }
    if(strike == 2) { //If strike = 2.
      if(dif == 1 && (*hand->cards[i]).suit == fs) { //If [i] suit is fs it adds to the Straight Flush.
    strike = 0;
    check++;
    if(check == 5) return 1; //If check is equal to 5, there is a Straight in hand.
    temp = *hand->cards[i];
    continue;
      }
      return 0;
    }
    //If strike = 0.
    if(dif == 0) continue; //If cards are the same, get next card.
    if(dif == 1 && (*hand->cards[i]).suit != fs) { /*If [i] is not Fs, the hand can still
                                                   contain a Straight Flush.*/
      strike = 1; //Sets strike to 1, so next card has to be the same value and suit == fs.
      continue;
    }
    if(dif == 1 && (*hand->cards[i]).suit == fs) { /*If dif is 1 and [i] is fs,
                                                   [i] is adding to the Straight Flush.*/
      check++;
      if(check == 5) return 1; //If check is equal to 5, there is a Straight in hand.
      temp = *hand->cards[i];
      continue;
    }
    if(dif > 1) return 0; //If dif > 1, there is no Straight in the hand.
  }
  return 0;
}

//Helper function that looks for Ace-low Straights.
int ace_straight_helper(deck_t *hand, size_t index, suit_t fs) {
  if(where_5_at(hand) == -1) return 0;
  //check receives 2, because we have the Ace on index 0 or 1, and the 5.
  int check = 2, dif = 0;
  card_t temp = *hand->cards[where_5_at(hand)];
  for(int i = where_5_at(hand); i < hand->n_cards; i++) {
    if(i == where_5_at(hand)) { //If first iteration, set temp to card at index of 5.
      temp = *hand->cards[i];
      continue;
    }
    dif = temp.value - (*hand->cards[i]).value;
    if(dif == 0) continue; //If value of both cards are the same, continue.
    if(dif == 1) { //If dif is 1, hand->cards[i] is adding to the Straight.
      check++;
      if(check == 5) return -1; //If check is equal to 5, there is a Straight in hand.
      temp = *hand->cards[i];
      continue;
    }
    if(dif > 1) return 0; //If dif > 1, there is no Straight in the hand.
  }
  return 0;
}
  
//Helper function that looks for Ace-low Straight Flushes.
int ace_straightFlush_helper(deck_t *hand, size_t index, suit_t fs) {
  if((*hand->cards[index]).suit != fs) return 0;
  if(where_5_at(hand) == -1) return 0;
  if((*hand->cards[where_5_at(hand)]).suit != fs) return 0;
  //check receives 2, because we have the Ace on index 0 or 1, and the 5.
  int check = 2, strike = 0, dif = 0;
  card_t temp = *hand->cards[where_5_at(hand)];
  for(int i = where_5_at(hand); i < hand->n_cards; i++) {
    if(i == where_5_at(hand)) { //If first iteration, set temp to card at index of 5.
      temp = *hand->cards[i];
      continue;
    }
    dif = temp.value - (*hand->cards[i]).value;
    //If strike = 1.
    if(strike == 1) {
      if(dif == 1 && (*hand->cards[i]).suit == fs) { /*If [i] suit is fs it adds
                                                     to the Straight Flush.*/
    strike = 0;
    check++;
    if(check == 5) return -1; //If check is equal to 5, there is a Straight in hand.
    temp = *hand->cards[i];
    continue;
      }
      if(dif == 1 && (*hand->cards[i]).suit != fs) {
    strike = 2;
    continue;
      }
      return 0;
    }
    if(strike == 2) { //If strike = 2.
      if(dif == 1 && (*hand->cards[i]).suit == fs) { //If [i] suit is fs it adds to the Straight Flush.
    strike = 0;
    check++;
    if(check == 5) return -1; //If check is equal to 5, there is a Straight in hand.
    temp = *hand->cards[i];
    continue;
      }
      return 0;
    }
    //If strike = 0.
    if(dif == 0) continue; //If cards are the same, get next card.
    if(dif == 1 && (*hand->cards[i]).suit != fs) { /*If [i] is not Fs, the hand can still
                                                   contain a Straight Flush.*/
      strike = 1; //Sets strike to 1, so next card, has to be the same value and suit = fs.
      continue;
    }
    if(dif == 1 && (*hand->cards[i]).suit == fs) { /*If dif is 1 and [i] is fs,
                                                   [i] is adding to the Straight Flush.*/
      check++;
      if(check == 5) return -1; //If check is equal to 5, there is a Straight Flush in hand.
      temp = *hand->cards[i];
      continue;
    }
    if(dif > 1) return 0; //If dif > 1, [i] is not adding to the Straight Flush.
  }
  return 0;
}

//Uses helper functions to look for Straights and Straight flushes.
int is_straight_at(deck_t * hand, size_t index, suit_t fs) {
  assert(hand->n_cards > 0);
  //Ace-low Straight.
  if((*hand->cards[index]).value == VALUE_ACE && fs == NUM_SUITS) {
    if(straight_helper(hand, index, fs) == 0) {
      //If straigh_helper returns 0, It looks for an Ace-low Straight.
      return ace_straight_helper(hand, index, fs);
    }else{
      return 1;
    }
    //Ace-low Straight Flush.
  }else if((*hand->cards[index]).value == VALUE_ACE && fs != NUM_SUITS) {
    if(straightFlush_helper(hand, index, fs) == 0) {
      //If straighFlush_helper returns 0, It looks for an Ace-low Straight Flush.
      return ace_straightFlush_helper(hand, index, fs);
    }else{
      return 1;
    }
  }
  //Regular Straight.
  if((*hand->cards[index]).value != VALUE_ACE && fs == NUM_SUITS) {
    return straight_helper(hand, index, fs);
    //Straight Flush.
  }else if((*hand->cards[index]).value != VALUE_ACE && fs != NUM_SUITS) {
    return straightFlush_helper(hand, index, fs);
  }
  return 0;
}

//Builds a hand with a Pair, 3 of a kind or a Full House.
hand_eval_t build_hand_from_match(deck_t * hand,
                  unsigned n,
                  hand_ranking_t what,
                  size_t idx) {
  assert(hand->n_cards > 4);
  hand_eval_t ans;
  ans.ranking = what;
  int count = 0;
  //Copies 'n' cards starting at 'idx'.
  for(int i = idx; i < idx + n; i++) {
    ans.cards[count] = hand->cards[i];
    count++;
  }
  //Copies the rest of the highest cards into the array.
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if((*hand->cards[i]).value == (*hand->cards[idx]).value) continue;
    ans.cards[count] = hand->cards[i];
    count++;
  }
  return ans;
}

//Sorts and compares two hands to get the winner.
int compare_hands(deck_t * hand1, deck_t * hand2) {
  //Sorts hand1 and hand2.
  qsort(hand1->cards, hand1->n_cards, sizeof(struct card_tag), card_ptr_comp);
  qsort(hand2->cards, hand2->n_cards, sizeof(struct card_tag), card_ptr_comp);
  
  //Compares the two hands.
  hand_eval_t cleanHand1 = evaluate_hand(hand1);
  hand_eval_t cleanHand2 = evaluate_hand(hand2);
  if(cleanHand1.ranking < cleanHand2.ranking) return 1;
  else if(cleanHand1.ranking > cleanHand2.ranking) return -1;
  else if(cleanHand1.ranking == cleanHand2.ranking) {
    int dif = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      dif = cleanHand1.cards[i]->value - cleanHand2.cards[i]->value;
      if(dif > 0) return 1;
      if(dif < 0) return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
  printf("Something went wrong call 911 right now!");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Use of uninitialised value" means exactly what it says.  In context of the line for which that message was reported, the uninitialized value must be that of `*hand->cards[i]` for some `i`.  That the issue is recognized by valgrind probably means that that expression designates part of a dynamically allocated object.  Note well that `malloc()` returns pointers to (formally) uninitialized memory.

I leave it to you to determine why the memory in question goes uninitialized in the case in question.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further? I've spent days trying to figure out what's wrong, even now with your answer, but I just can't.

Comment: @AdrielAmorim, before you attempt to read any particular memory location, you must ensure that it has a meaningful value stored in it.  For memory dynamically allocated via `malloc()`, that means writing values to the specific bytes you are trying to read before the first attempt to read them.  This is what Valgrind says you have failed to do.  If I were to hazard a guess, I'd wager that you have an off-by-one error somewhere.  That is, you write initial values to one fewer element than you need or intend to do.

Comment: Thank you so so much! The error was in `build_hand_from_match` where I assumed `n` was going to be 1 or higher, but it could be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the memory allocated using `malloc` with a call to `memset`, before operating on the allocated memory.

```
void* ptr = malloc(sizeof(hand));
memset(ptr, 0, sizeof(hand));
```

Comment: Although this might silence Valgrind, it probably just disguises the underlying problem.